# Counting stuff in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-local-storage

In my .NET program, I want to count the number of times a piece of code will be hit. To make it a bit more challenging, my code is usually executed in multiple threads and I cannot control the creation / destruction of threads (and don't know when they are created)... they can even be pooled. Say:

```
class Program
{
    static int counter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Parallel.For(0, 100000000, (a) =>
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
            });

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
}
```

As the performance counter and method are hit quite a few times, I'd like to use a 'normal' variable in contrast to an atomic / interlocked integer. My second attempt was therefore to use threadlocal storage in combination with IDisposable to speed things up. Because I cannot control creation/destruction, I have to keep track of the storage variables:

```
class Program
{
    static int counter = 0;

    // I don't know when threads are created / joined, which is why I need this:
    static List<WeakReference<ThreadLocalValue>> allStorage = 
        new List<WeakReference<ThreadLocalValue>>();

    // The performance counter
    [ThreadStatic]
    static ThreadLocalValue local;

    class ThreadLocalValue : IDisposable
    {
        public ThreadLocalValue()
        {
            lock (allStorage)
            {
                allStorage.Add(new WeakReference<ThreadLocalValue>(this));
            }
        }

        public int ctr = 0;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Atomic add and exchange
            int tmp = Interlocked.Exchange(ref ctr, 0); // atomic set to 0-with-read
            Interlocked.Add(ref Program.counter, tmp); // atomic add
        }

        ~ThreadLocalValue()
        {
            // Make sure it's merged.
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    // Create-or-increment
    static void LocalInc()
    {
        if (local == null) { local = new ThreadLocalValue(); } 
        ++local.ctr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Parallel.For(0, 100000000, (a) =>
            {
                LocalInc();
            });

        lock (allStorage)
        {
            foreach (var item in allStorage)
            {
                ThreadLocalValue target;
                if (item.TryGetTarget(out target))
                {
                    target.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My question is: can we do this faster and/or prettier?

Comment: Do you know accessing a `ThreadStatic` field will be far slower than a shared atomic increment. You're making it worse. Are you facing any performance problems?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Run the tests please. The original version with `Interlocked.Increment` executes in 1,6 seconds here, while the second version runs in 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @atlaste You were right... There is another potential pitfall: `Dispose()` could be called twice: the `GC` runs after the end of the thread, see that `ThreadLocalValue` has a finalizer and put it in the finalization queue. The TLV isnt GCed at this point. The finalizer queue runs on another thread, and decides to run. `Dispose()` is executed in the finalizer thread, while the "main" thread loads the WF for the TLV, succeeding, because the TLV hasn't been collected, so the "main" thread executes the `Dispose()`.

Comment: @atlaste Now there are two `Dispose()` running at the same time. Both could execute the `Interlocked.Increment()` before doing the `ctr = 0`, adding twice the `ctr`.

Comment: @xanatos You're right; that can easily be fixed by using Exchange with a value instantiated to 0.

Comment: @atlaste https://ideone.com/kGsLjk And the `List<>` isn't locked... Changed a little to support Exchange and lock for `List<>`, and a `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: @xanatos thanks, you're right. PS: `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` aren't necessary in this case I think, as long as you use the exchange.

Comment: @atlaste The `GC.Suppress` is useless, but the `GC.Wait..` is necessary: you could have a finalizer running that executes the `Interl.Exchange`, then its thread is paused by the scheduler, the `foreach` executes the `Dispose()`, but doing the `Interl.Exchange` it gets 0 (because the finalizer `Interl.Exchange` has already removed the value), so it doesn't add anything... The main thread runs like a train, without waiting for the finalizer thread... Now you are at the `Console.WriteLine`, and you execute it before the finalizer `Exchange.Increment` is done.

Comment: @xanatos OK that's +3 points for you for spotting that :-)

Comment: @atlaste Doing "quick" multithreaded code correctly is very hard :-)

Comment: @xanatos Yes... (no pain no game :-) still, I'm wondering if my solution can be implemented even faster. I guess at some point you need a threadlocal either way, so the answer is 'no' - but I'm not really certain.

Answer (score 1):

**What you need is a thread-safe, nonblocking, [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx), [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variable to perform the counting for you.**

---

Thanks goodness, the .NET framework provides managed ways to perform what you want.

For starters, you need a volatile, static variable to be used as a counter. Declare it like (where all your threads can access it):

```
public static volatile int volatileCounter;
```

Where *static* means this is a class and not an instance member, and *volatile* prevents caching errors from happening.

Next, you will need a code that increments it in a thread-safe and nonblocking way. If you don't expect your counter to exceed the limits of the int variable (which is very likely), you can use the [Interlocked class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that like:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref yourInstance.volatileCounter);
```

The [interlocked class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will guarantee that your increment operation will be **atomic** so no race condition can cause false results, and it is also non-blocking in the manner of on heavy-weighted [sync objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) and thread blocking is involved here.

Comment: Ehm... this is what I started my question with? My `ThreadStatic` solution is actually much faster.

Comment: @atlaste Where did you start your question with that? I have re-read and was not able to find it. Also - knowing the underlying system in details - I strongly doubt that there is a thread-safe solution which is faster than mine. I can imagine a solution being equally fast under certain conditions, but that's all (because the variable **has** to be volatile to avoid caching errors, and the fastest way to perform non-blocking thread safe incrementation is _InterlockedIncrement()_ which is called by the interlocked class in the background).

Comment: Ok it seems we misunderstand each other. I've started with an implementation of `Interlocked.Increment` in my question, after which I noted "I'd like to use a 'normal' variable in contrast to an atomic / interlocked integer". The requirement is that the performance counter has to have the correct value _after_ program execution. Consistency across threads during execution is not a requirement. Because of this relaxed constraint, you can argue that `Interlocked` is too heavy weight for what I want to do, and therefore a better implementation should be possible without atomic access.

Comment: The normal execution pattern is that a single thread does a lot of PC updates. On possible solution (the one I proposed) is based on the idea that during thread execution, it would be nice if the PC updates are happening within normal variables (which allows caching etc). However, when the thread finishes, it should merge everything back to get the right values. However, the only way I was able to do that is to hack a ThreadStatic / IDisposable.

Comment: @atlaste I think I see what you are trying to achieve now, but for that you neither need the interlocked class, nor a ThreadStatic variable. You just have to make your per-instance counter public, and sum them after all your threads are finished.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want :-) But AFAIK there's no general way to do that, other than using the `ThreadStatic` / `IDisposable` hack I did. I cannot control thread creation / destruction, and I cannot pass instances across methods since I don't control their signatures. Moreover, exposing a singleton without any synchronization will give undefined behavior.

Comment: PS: you can discard the `volatile` in your first line of code. Interlocked already takes care of that.

Comment: @atlaste Are you sure? (I'm not that confident in this aspect, than in the others.) In C++ you **have to** declare the variable volatile to prevent the compiler from creating optimization hacks that might create a template variable, which would cause a Heisenbug. In case of C# it might not be necessary but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes I'm very sure, C# ain't C++ :-) Just try it, it'll actually generate a compiler warning. Also, I'm pretty sure there's Q/A on this subject on StackOverflow as well.